# LightGBM vs Sklearn LightGBM- Mistake in Implementation- Exact same parameters giving different results

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

While passing the exact same parameters to LightGBM and sklearn's implementation of LightGBM, I am getting different results. Initially, I was getting the exact same results on doing this, however, I made some changes to my code and now I can't find out why they're not coming the same. This means that the performance metrics and feature importance are coming differently. Please help me figure it out, I can't figure out the mistake I am making. It could either be a mistake in the way I am implementing LightGBM using the original library or in sklearn's implementation. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077816/light-gbm-python-api-vs-scikit-learn-api/51077977#51077977) for explanation on why we should get identical results.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_dummy[df_merge.columns], labels, test_size=0.25,random_state=42)

n_folds = 5

lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(x_train, y_train)

def objective(params, n_folds = n_folds):
    """Objective function for Gradient Boosting Machine Hyperparameter Tuning"""

    print(params)

    params['max_depth'] = int(params['max_depth'])
    params['num_leaves'] = int(params['num_leaves'])

    params['min_child_samples'] = int(params['min_child_samples'])
    params['subsample_freq'] = int(params['subsample_freq'])

    # Perform n_fold cross validation with hyperparameters

    # Use early stopping and evalute based on ROC AUC
    cv_results = lgb.cv(params, lgb_train, nfold=n_folds, num_boost_round=10000, 
                        early_stopping_rounds=100, metrics='auc')

    # Extract the best score
    best_score = max(cv_results['auc-mean'])

    # Loss must be minimized
    loss = 1 - best_score
    num_iteration = int(np.argmax(cv_results['auc-mean']) + 1)

    of_connection = open(out_file, 'a')
    writer = csv.writer(of_connection)
    writer.writerow([loss, params, num_iteration])

    # Dictionary with information for evaluation
    return {'loss': loss, 'params': params, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'estimators': num_iteration}

space = {
    'min_child_samples': hp.quniform('min_child_samples', 5, 100, 5), 
    'reg_alpha': hp.uniform('reg_alpha', 0.0, 1.0),
    'reg_lambda': hp.uniform('reg_lambda', 0.0, 1.0),
    'colsample_bytree': hp.uniform('colsample_bytree', 0.5, 1.0),
    'max_depth' : hp.quniform('max_depth', 3, 10, 1),
    'subsample' : hp.quniform('subsample', 0.6, 1, 0.05),
    'num_leaves': hp.quniform('num_leaves', 20, 150, 1),  
    'subsample_freq': hp.quniform('subsample_freq',0,10,1),
    'min_gain_to_split': hp.quniform('min_gain_to_split', 0.01, 0.1, 0.01),


    'learning_rate' : 0.05,
    'objective' : 'binary',

}

out_file = 'results/gbm_trials.csv'
of_connection = open(out_file, 'w')
writer = csv.writer(of_connection)

writer.writerow(['loss', 'params', 'estimators'])
of_connection.close()

trials = Trials()
best = fmin(objective, space, algo=tpe.suggest, trials=trials, max_evals=10)
bayes_trials_results = sorted(trials.results, key = lambda x: x['loss'])

results = pd.read_csv('results/gbm_trials.csv')

# Sort with best scores on top and reset index for slicing
results.sort_values('loss', ascending = True, inplace = True)
results.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
results.head()
best_bayes_estimators = int(results.loc[0, 'estimators'])

best['max_depth'] = int(best['max_depth'])
best['num_leaves'] = int(best['num_leaves'])

best['min_child_samples'] = int(best['min_child_samples'])

num_boost_round=int(best_bayes_estimators * 1.1)
best['objective'] = 'binary'
best['boosting_type'] = 'gbdt'

best['subsample_freq'] = int(best['subsample_freq'])

#Actual LightGBM

best_gbm = lgb.train(params=best, train_set=lgb_train, num_boost_round=num_boost_round)
    
#Sklearn's Implementation of LightGBM

best_sk = dict(best)
del best_sk['min_gain_to_split']
sk_best_gbm = lgb.LGBMClassifier(**best_sk, n_estimators=num_boost_round, learning_rate=0.05, min_split_gain=best['min_gain_to_split'])
sk_best_gbm.fit(x_train, y_train)

sk_best_gbm.get_params()
```

Comment: could you trim your code to the parts that are essential to the question? I think that might be helpful for folks

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/58438962/10495893

Comment: I might be overlooking it (+1 to oW_'s comment), but I don't see any attempt to fix a random seed; there's some randomness in GBMs, so even if you run the native lightgbm api twice in a row you'd expect to see slightly different results.

Comment: @BenReiniger I am sorry for the cross-posting, learning how these platforms work and need a solution very soon. I have trimmed the code by removing the parts related to the performance metrics and feature importance plotting.
If I run the native lightgbm api twice in a row, I get exactly the same results in the second and first run. Initially, I was getting the exact same results in sklearn's lightgbm as well as the native api, but after making a few code changes to the parameters and syntax, this is no longer happening. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @oW_ I have trimmed the code by removing the parts related to the performance metrics and feature importance plotting.

Answer (score 1):

A kind soul from Github was able to [answer this](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2517).

The answer is this:
for the parameters consistency problem, you can try to use a new lgb_train before lgb.train, like

```
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(x_train, y_train)
best_gbm = lgb.train(params=best, train_set=lgb_train, num_boost_round=num_boost_round)
```

lgb_train is lazy-inited, and only inited one-time, so it will be constructed in the cv part. And some parameters (like min_child_samples) in that part may change the lgb_train. Therefore, lgb_train may is inited by different parameters. (So it is better to use a new lgb.train in cv part as well.)